# Change (not remove) "fortunes" in Linux Mint console

Tags: command-line, linux-mint

I don't mind the idea of quotes when I load the Mint console, however the OEM text leaves much to be desired.  I'd like to update the quote text with inspirational or otherwise useful quotes.

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Editing Linux Mint fortunes! (Mint 13)](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/933) has some good information for how to tweak what "fortunes" are displayed.

In specific, it appears they are stored in `/usr/share/cowsay/cows` (as plain text, preformatted) with `.cow` extension.

There's more information in the link.

Answer (score 3):

Under Mint, there's a little script, `mint-fortune`, which is called at the end of `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

It's essentially a wrapper around the program `fortune`, which is the base program for printing fortunes, and the programs responsible for drawing the fortune-teller.

Unfortunately for you, the script does not accept arguments, so you'll have to remove it or comment it out in `/etc/bash.bashrc`, and write your own solution:

- Either you want to keep the little animal (Yay!), and you'll have to write a modified version of `mint-fortune`
- Or you simply use `fortune`

In either case, you write your fortune in a file with the appropriate format (apparently simply a text file where fortunes are separated by a `%` on a line) and call whatever makes you happy in your `.bashrc`.

Comment: If you are writing your own fortunes file, see the man page for `strfile(1)` -- it creates the accompanying `.dat` file.

Answer (score 0):

(since these answers didn't work in my case)

i wrote simple **alnternative to fortune**, here:

https://github.com/berrytsakala/dailytip

- it's dead simple to change the quotes database
- there's no "installer" yet, but installing is also easy.
- it's python - easy to modify the source
- no bells or whistles,

it's good enough for me. You're welcome to suggest new features :)

Answer (score 0):

Using "$@" worked for me:

1- Within the function show_fortune:

`/usr/games/fortune`**`"$@"`**`| $command -f $cow`

2- Invoking it:

`show_fortune`**`"$@"`**

**Full listing**

```
#!/bin/bash

function show_fortune {
   RANGE=3
   number=$RANDOM
   let "number %= $RANGE"
   case $number in
       0)
           cow="moose"
           ;;
       1)
           cow="tux"
           ;;
       2)
           cow="koala"
           ;;   
   esac

   RANGE=2
   number=$RANDOM
   let "number %= $RANGE"
   case $number in
       0)
           command="/usr/games/cowsay"
           ;;
       1)
           command="/usr/games/cowthink"
           ;;
   esac
   /usr/games/fortune "$@" | $command -f $cow
}

showfortunes=`gsettings get com.linuxmint.terminal show-fortunes 2>/dev/null`
if [ "$showfortunes" == "true" ]; then
    show_fortune "$@"
fi
```